# Nominatim - XML respond at same PHP file

Tags: php, xml, openstreetmap, nominatim

I have php file that have the url variable

```
$url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?`format=xml&lat=31.130948&lon=-94.470355&addressdetails=1";`
```

sending the url by codes below:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

how can I receive the respond on same php file and put each XML item into variable ?

The respond from nominatim server is very long XML file, I need only to process the small part as below :

```
<addressparts>
<road>County Road 357</road>
<hamlet>Nancy</hamlet>
<county>Angelina County</county>
<state>Texas</state>
<country>United States of America</country>
<country_code>us</country_code>
</addressparts>
```

Comment: You need to utilize an XML parser in your PHP script. Or alternatively a JSON parser since Nominatim can also return JSON instead of XML.

Comment: I am beginner level PHP programmer, I don't know exactly how to do it

Comment: I need only City, State and Zip code information and dump the rest

Comment: :( Apparently I forgotten, I need your kind help.

Comment: I suggest to re-ask your question but this time focus on your actual problem: parsing XML or JSON in PHP. But I guess there are already various examples and tutorials about this topic on the Internet.